# nextjs cant get data every second

Tags: next.js

```js
import { Link } from "@nextui-org/link";
import { Snippet } from "@nextui-org/snippet";
import { Code } from "@nextui-org/code"
import { button as buttonStyles } from "@nextui-org/theme";
import { siteConfig } from "@/config/site";
import { title, subtitle } from "@/components/primitives";


import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { promises } from "dns";



type SensorData = {
    gases: [string, number][];
    humedades: [string, number][];
    temperaturas: [string, number][];
  }
  

async function getData():Promise<SensorData> {
  
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/get_recent", {
      method: "GET",
      next: {
        revalidate: 1
      }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
   
    return data;
    
  }


export default async function Home() {
    const [data] = await Promise.all([getData()]);
    const temperaturaData = data.temperaturas;
    const humidityData = data.humedades;
    const gasData = data.gases;
    const temperature = temperaturaData[0][1];
    const humidity = humidityData[0][1];
    const gas = gasData[0][1];
    
    return (
        <>
        <section className="items-center justify-center gap-4 py-8 md:py-10 flex flex-col content-center    ">
            <div className=" text-center justify-center">
                <h1 className={title({ color: "pink" })}>Fire&nbsp;</h1>
                <h1 className={title()}>Tech &nbsp;</h1>
                <br />
                
                <h2 className={subtitle({ class: "mt-4" })}>
                    Prevé, detecta y controla incendios accidentales
                </h2>
            </div>

            
        </section>
        <section className="items-center justify-center gap-4 py-8 md:py-10 flex flex-col content-center    ">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 w-3/4 content-center  ">
          <Card>
            <CardHeader >
                <b>Temperatura</b>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody className="text-center text-2xl">{temperature}°C</CardBody>
            <CardFooter className="text-7xl text-center"></CardFooter>
          </Card>
            <Card>
                <CardHeader className="text-center">
                <b>Humedad</b>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="text-center text-2xl">{humidity}%</CardBody>
                <CardFooter className="text-7xl text-center"></CardFooter>
            </Card>
            <Card>
                <CardHeader className="text-center">
                <b>Gas</b>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="text-center text-2xl">{gas}</CardBody>
                <CardFooter></CardFooter>
            </Card>
        </div>
        </section>
        
        </>

    );
}
```

I have this code for a demo, and I want to get the data from the API every second and change it on the UI. I am new to this. Can anyone help?

I tried not to cache and revalidate the data, but it only changes every time I press cmd r, so I don't know what to do. it is only one page and i cant get it to work

I need the data to refresh every second or every 5 seconds but it can do it

Comment: If you want to change Ui as per the data changes such as Scoreboard or something. Use Reatlime Db. Calling APis every second doesn't make sense. Realtime DBs have sockets and events that update the UI on data manipulation events.